# The items in the list of figures are to be hyperlinked

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I have used `\usepackage{hperref}`

The items in the *Table of Contents* are clickable hyperlinks, i.e., when I click the Chapter or section or subsection name in the list, I am taken to the relevant page.

But the items in the *list of figures* that follow Table of contents are not hyper linked.

I would greatly appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: well they are links by default. So don't let us guess what you are doing differently, show a small but complete example.

Comment: After some attempts, I got it working! I put the `\mainmatter` after the line `\listoffigures`.  Thanks for the quick response.